# Applying non interger values in loop counter and/or subset function, R

Tags: r, function, loops, subset

I have a large data frame (flightFPN, sample below) with data corresponding to distinct groups. The objects within one group have different volumes and I was plotting the number of objects within each group over a certain threshold volume using this function:

```
subflight=subset(flightFPN,Volume>2)
subflightgrouped=data.frame(table(subflight$Cell.ID))
hist(subflightFPN$Volume, breaks=seq(0,11,.2), freq=TRUE, main="Foci          
Volume >2, Flight", xlab="Volume")
```

using the mean function, I also looked at the average number of foci for all the objects given this particular volume cutoff.

```
   m=mean(subflightgrouped,Freq)
```

What I would like to do though is make a plot of this average number of foci per group as a function of the cutoff that I use, (ie what is the average number of foci per group when I make a cutoff at volumes >1 or >1.1 etc.

I've been trying lots of variations of the code below to no avail. What I would like is for the volume cutoff to go from .5 to 10 in steps of .1.  I think an input of "for (i in seq(.5,10,.1) would be better but that doesn't work at all. What I have below though is the closest I've come to something that works, it outputs just the result when the Volume cutoff is 1 and nothing else. Any help would be very much appreciated!

```
 for (i in 1,10)

   {
   largeFPNflight=subset(flightFPN, Volume > i)
   largeFPNflightgrouped=data.frame(table(largeFPNflight$Cell.ID))
   m=mean(largeFPNflightgrouped$Freq)
 }


 plot(i,m)
```

As far as the sample dataframe, flightFPN, the Cell.ID category refers to one particular group. So for example S101006F5 is a family of 8 objects (ID 0 through 7) each with a unique volume. Another group is S101006F4 which is a family of 9 objects (0 through 8).

```
 File      Volume   Unit    SO  ID  Cell.ID
 S101006F   0.27    um^3    5   0   S101006F5
 S101006F   0.09    um^3    5   1   S101006F5
 S101006F   3.90    um^3    5   2   S101006F5
 S101006F   0.16    um^3    5   3   S101006F5
 S101006F   0.03    um^3    5   4   S101006F5
 S101006F   0.06    um^3    5   5   S101006F5
 S101006F   0.13    um^3    5   6   S101006F5
 S101006F   0.21    um^3    5   7   S101006F5
 S101006F   0.02    um^3    4   0   S101006F4
 S101006F   0.44    um^3    4   1   S101006F4
 S101006F   0.26    um^3    4   2   S101006F4
 S101006F   0.06    um^3    4   3   S101006F4
 S101006F   0.09    um^3    4   4   S101006F4
 S101006F   0.02    um^3    4   5   S101006F4
 S101006F   0.03    um^3    4   6   S101006F4
 S101006F   0.22    um^3    4   7   S101006F4
 S101006F   0.03    um^3    4   8   S101006F4
 S101006F   0.03    um^3    3   0   S101006F3
 S101006F   1.65    um^3    3   1   S101006F3
 S101006F   0.14    um^3    3   2   S101006F3
 S101006F   0.02    um^3    3   3   S101006F3
 S101006F   0.01    um^3    2   0   S101006F2
 S101006F   0.08    um^3    2   1   S101006F2
 S101006F   0.75    um^3    2   2   S101006F2
 S101006F   0.03    um^3    2   3   S101006F2
 S101006F   0.05    um^3    2   4   S101006F2
 S101006F   0.02    um^3    2   5   S101006F2
 S101006F   0.23    um^3    2   6   S101006F2
 S101006F   0.04    um^3    2   7   S101006F2
 S101006F   0.03    um^3    2   8   S101006F2
 S101006F   0.25    um^3    2   9   S101006F2
 S101006F   0.02    um^3    2   10  S101006F2
 S101006F   0.02    um^3    2   11  S101006F2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that you need to store the means to access later, because you keep overwriting them. While very intuitive (especially when you have a background in another language), for-loops are not the way to go most of the time. Here is a possible solution in base-R, using lapply.

First, we initiate a vector of thresholds:

```
my_thresholds <- seq(0,10,0.5)
```

Then we use lapply to perform a custom function for each threshold:

```
res <- lapply(my_thresholds, function(x){
  #table by cell ID
  temp_table <- with(dat[dat$Volume>x,],table(Cell.ID))
  #return threshold used and mean of frequencies
  return(c(threshold=x,mean_freq=mean(temp_table)))
})
```

This can be bound together to the right format for plotting:

```
res <- do.call(rbind,res)
```